# Trying to figure out which variables it makes sense to use as predictors for modelling flight delays

Tags: regression, modeling, linear-model

I am working on a task to predict flight delays. My dataset contains about 6 million records of flights in the US recorded over one year.
The dataset contains the following variables:

[image]

I am informed that the last moment available for prediction is the scheduled time of departure. As you can see, I don't have information on the weather. Most variables have very low correlation with the target (< 0.1). The exception are the delay variables (CARRIER_DELAY, NAS_DELAY, etc) which have meaningful correlations (up to 0.6).
The thing is, I am not sure if it makes sense to use such variables, because it is not clear to me whether they are available at the moment of scheduled departure. How does it look like to you?

Comment: I think it makes a lot of sense to talk to the people who will be using this model in the future to make predictions.  What data will they have available?  How will they use the model?  What do they want from it?  How statistically savvy are they?  Etc.  That's foundational information you need to have before you even start to build a predictive model.

Comment: You have tagged this with `[regression]` & `[linear-model]`.  Since you want to predict delays, you probably want a survival model, unless flights can leave early & you also want to predict by how much (which doesn't match my experience).  Furthermore, you may want to read some of our existing threads on [tag:feature-selection] to learn from what has already been discussed on the site.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica thanks for the comments. In fact I thought that I should try a survival model, but I have never studied so I would prefer to stick to regression that I am more familiar with. I thought that maybe it would be sensible to apply a log transformation to the flight delay instead. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: It's better to use the right tool for the job.  It's time to study survival models.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, ok you are right. I ll try that. Do you have any recommendations on where to start?

Comment: You could start with [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survival%2breferences?tab=Votes).

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica thank you. One last dumb question from someone that have never worked with survival analysis before. Is it straightforward with survival analysis to obtain predictions (expected delay) for new entries and calculate the error on test set, as we do with regression analysis? Or it works differently?

Comment: Try [this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsurvival%5d%20prediction%20is%3aquestion).